# Multiple Problems Installing 12.04, now can't use Windows

Tags: installation, grub2, dual-boot, partitioning, wubi

First I tried using the 32-bit wubi.exe installer from the main Ubuntu website.  It worked fine, dual booted with Windows 7 and all.  I tried installing several applications and got errors.  After searching for a little while for a fix, I found that someone else had solved the problem by uninstalling the 32-bit version and installing 64-bit Ubuntu.

Apparently there is no wubi.exe installer for the 64-bit version, so I used LinuxLive to put the iso file onto a USB drive.  I changed my the boot order in BIOS to check the USB first.  It did, and I got into the Ubuntu installer just fine.

Everything was working fine, but then I got an error that GRUB could not be installed. I chose "install manually later" or something like that.  Immediately, the installer said it was done and ready for a reboot.  At this point, my USB is still in the computer.  The computer reboots...and it's back at the installer for the USB.  I look up what's going on here, and someone says in a thread they solved it by selecting "Try Ubuntu" then installing it via a shortcut on the desktop.  I assumed that Ubuntu simply hadn't installed and it would be safe to try again, so I did.  It finished installing, this time I chose a different partition that wasn't being used.  The thread also said to reinstall grub to the mounted drive, so I did that.

Next I took out my USB and rebooted.  I get stuck on the GRUB GNU loader, v.1.99 or something I believe it says at the top.  I can't do anything, and it doesn't detect Windows 7 OR Ubuntu.  When I check partitions, I have two 43 GB partitions that both have the same files in them (I'm assuming those are the two Ubuntu installations), and can only run Ubuntu off of my USB-- and can't run Windows 7 at all, however from within Ubuntu the windows 7 filesystem and files can still be seen.

I have no idea what to do now.  I used Ubuntu in the past (9.xx) and never had these sorts of problems!  Please help.  And sorry for the wall of text.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do. Do you want to remove all Ubuntu (WUBI and in-partition) and go back to Windows? Do you want to delete Windows and use the whole computer for Ubuntu? Do you want to uninstall WUBI and install Ubuntu in its own partition?

Comment: I want to have Windows and Ubuntu in separate partitions.

Answer (score 1):

To be clear lets recap what you did.

1. You installed Ubuntu via WUBI
2. You installed Ubuntu in separate partition twice.
3. The second thing installed GRUB2 and interfered with WUBI install
   and now you have a unbootable system

We will try to uninstall all the Ubuntu installations and keep Windows. Then we will install Ubuntu again properly.

**First,** undo GRUB and fix MBR so that Windows can boot again.

- Follow the first part of [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on) to remove GRUB and put fixMBR. in particular, boot from Windows 7 rescue CD and open the Command Prompt and type:

  `bootrec /fixmbr`

  `bootrec /fixboot`

  `bootrec /rebuildBcd`
- Take the CD out and reboot.

This should boot your Windows 7.

**Second,** Uninstall WUBI installation of Ubuntu. At this point WUBI installation is not bootable and there may not be an easy way to recover any data files you put in there. by uninstalling Ubuntu via WUBI, we will recover the lost disk space.

While in Windows 7, go to "Control Panel > Programs and Features" and scroll down to Ubuntu and uninstall. If all goes well, Wubi Ubuntu will be gone forever.

**Third,** Delete all the previous Ubuntu partitions.

- Boot from the Ubuntu live USB and choose "Try Ubuntu."
- Search for the program Gparted and run it. Delete all the `ext4` and
  `swap` partitions. Do not create any new partitions, Ubuntu
  installation will find the unused space and create them again. make
  sure you are not deleting any ntfs (Windows) partitions. Click
  "Apply." Exit Gparted.

**Fourth,** Install Ubuntu

- Now click "Install Ubuntu" icon while running Ubuntu from the Live
  USB. It should recognize the presence of Windows 7 and offer to install Ubuntu in the unused space. If not abort installation and ask a question here again.

I hope this works for you, but I can't guarantee success. Follow at your own risk.